# silverlight child window style dissables the window close button

Tags: silverlight, styles, childwindow

I'm using a style for my child window in my Silverlight application.
It seems that when i use that style the close button of the childwindw is dissabled.
If i don't use the style on the child window than the close button works fine.

this is the style i use for the child window:

```
<Style TargetType="sdk:ChildWindow" x:Key="ChildWindowStyle">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Cycle"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="HasCloseButton" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="OverlayBrush" Value="#7F000000"/>
        <Setter Property="OverlayOpacity" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:ChildWindow">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1F3B53"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                            <Grid x:Name="grid" Background="#02FFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="15">
                                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz2">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz1">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz0">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.95" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="X"/>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.85" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="X"/>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz2">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz1">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz0">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="X"/>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <Path x:Name="X_Fuzz2" Data="F1 M 6.742676,3.852539 L 9.110840,1.559570 L 8.910645,0.500000 L 6.838379,0.500000 L 4.902832,2.435547 L 2.967285,0.500000 L 0.895020,0.500000 L 0.694824,1.559570 L 3.062988,3.852539 L 0.527832,6.351563 L 0.689941,7.600586 L 2.967285,7.600586 L 4.897949,5.575195 L 6.854004,7.600586 L 9.115723,7.600586 L 9.277832,6.351563 L 6.742676,3.852539 Z" Fill="#14C51900" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="8" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Fill" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="9" StrokeLineJoin="Bevel" StrokeStartLineCap="Round">
                                                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                        <TransformGroup>
                                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1.3" ScaleX="1.3"/>
                                                        </TransformGroup>
                                                    </Path.RenderTransform>
                                                </Path>
                                                <Path x:Name="X_Fuzz1" Data="F1 M 6.742676,3.852539 L 9.110840,1.559570 L 8.910645,0.500000 L 6.838379,0.500000 L 4.902832,2.435547 L 2.967285,0.500000 L 0.895020,0.500000 L 0.694824,1.559570 L 3.062988,3.852539 L 0.527832,6.351563 L 0.689941,7.600586 L 2.967285,7.600586 L 4.897949,5.575195 L 6.854004,7.600586 L 9.115723,7.600586 L 9.277832,6.351563 L 6.742676,3.852539 Z" Fill="#1EC51900" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="8" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Fill" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="9" StrokeLineJoin="Bevel" StrokeStartLineCap="Round">
                                                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                        <TransformGroup>
                                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1.1" ScaleX="1.1"/>
                                                        </TransformGroup>
                                                    </Path.RenderTransform>
                                                </Path>
                                                <Path x:Name="X_Fuzz0" Data="F1 M 6.742676,3.852539 L 9.110840,1.559570 L 8.910645,0.500000 L 6.838379,0.500000 L 4.902832,2.435547 L 2.967285,0.500000 L 0.895020,0.500000 L 0.694824,1.559570 L 3.062988,3.852539 L 0.527832,6.351563 L 0.689941,7.600586 L 2.967285,7.600586 L 4.897949,5.575195 L 6.854004,7.600586 L 9.115723,7.600586 L 9.277832,6.351563 L 6.742676,3.852539 Z" Fill="#FFC51900" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="8" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Stretch="Fill" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="9" StrokeLineJoin="Bevel" StrokeStartLineCap="Round"/>
                                                <Path x:Name="X" Data="F1 M 6.742676,3.852539 L 9.110840,1.559570 L 8.910645,0.500000 L 6.838379,0.500000 L 4.902832,2.435547 L 2.967285,0.500000 L 0.895020,0.500000 L 0.694824,1.559570 L 3.062988,3.852539 L 0.527832,6.351563 L 0.689941,7.600586 L 2.967285,7.600586 L 4.897949,5.575195 L 6.854004,7.600586 L 9.115723,7.600586 L 9.277832,6.351563 L 6.742676,3.852539 Z" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="8" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="0.7" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="9" StrokeLineJoin="Bevel" StrokeStartLineCap="Round"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WindowStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Open">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Overlay">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(Children)[0].ScaleX" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="0"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="1"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0,0,0.5,1" KeyTime="00:00:00.45" Value="1.05"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.55" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(Children)[0].ScaleY" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="0"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="1"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0,0,0.5,1" KeyTime="00:00:00.45" Value="1.05"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.55" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Overlay">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(Children)[0].ScaleX" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="1.05"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.45" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(Children)[0].ScaleY" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="1.05"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.45" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="Overlay" Background="{TemplateBinding OverlayBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Opacity="{TemplateBinding OverlayOpacity}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <Border BorderBrush="#14000000" BorderThickness="1" Background="#14000000" CornerRadius="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <Border BorderBrush="#0F000000" BorderThickness="1" Background="#0F000000" CornerRadius="2.25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            <Border BorderBrush="#0C000000" BorderThickness="1" Background="#0C000000" CornerRadius="2.5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            <Border BorderBrush="#0A000000" BorderThickness="1" Background="#0A000000" CornerRadius="2.75" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="#FFFFFFFF" CornerRadius="1" BorderBrush="#FF5D9BC5">
                                <Border CornerRadius="1.5">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFDFDEDE" Offset="1"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFF5F4F4" Offset="0"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Border.Background>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="0.269*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="0.731*"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Border x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="#FF999898" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Width="Auto" Height="33">
                                            <Border.Effect>
                                                <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.3" ShadowDepth="3" BlurRadius="3"/>
                                            </Border.Effect>
                                            <Border.Background>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1.043" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF5C9AC4" Offset="1"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF75B1DA" Offset="0.402"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF75B1DA" Offset="0.502"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF5C9AC4" Offset="0.506"/>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Border.Background>
                                            <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False" Margin="6,0,6,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="14"/>
                                                <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="14" IsTabStop="False" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="15" IsEnabled="True"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                        <Border Background="Transparent" Margin="7" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" BorderBrush="#FF72A6BF" BorderThickness="0">
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Margin="5"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Is anyone familiar with this problem?
Thanks for any reply!!

Comment: the style is fine, must be something else causing it

Comment: but the problem occures only when applying the style. Do you know if the style might influence other hidden files?

Comment: do you mean the little cross button on the top right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might find what the problem is.

Can you try removing the `DropShadowEffect` under the `Border` named `Chrome`? For same reason, it hangs the CPU...